# Hibernate Envers dont create revisions

Tags: java, database, hibernate, revision, hibernate-envers

I have a problem with hibernate envers. I added the eventlisteners and I added the @Audited Annotation, but when I change the name (or anything else) there are no revisions in the database created. I hope you can help me.

This is the Main class where I build the session etc.

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        ServiceRegistryBuilder registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
        registry.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = registry.buildServiceRegistry();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration
                .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Address address1 = new Address();
        address1.setStreetName("Privet Drive");
        address1.setHouseNumber(4);
        Person person1 = new Person();


        person1.setName("Hi");
        person1.setSurname("test");
        person1.setAddress(address1);

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(person1);
        session.persist(address1);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        person1.setName("Hans");

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(person1);
        session.persist(address1);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();


    }

}
```

Here the Person class:

```
package Main;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import org.hibernate.envers.RevisionEntity;
import org.hibernate.envers.RevisionNumber;
import org.hibernate.envers.RevisionTimestamp;

@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
@Audited
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @RevisionNumber
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    private String username;

    @ManyToOne
    private Address address;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

The adress:

```
package Main;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

@Entity
@Table(name="ADDRESS")
@Audited
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String streetName;

    private Integer houseNumber;

    private Integer flatNumber;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address")
    private Set<Person> persons;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }

    public Integer getHouseNumber() {
        return houseNumber;
    }

    public Integer getFlatNumber() {
        return flatNumber;
    }

    public Set<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }

    public void setHouseNumber(Integer houseNumber) {
        this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
    }

    public void setFlatNumber(Integer flatNumber) {
        this.flatNumber = flatNumber;
    }

    public void setPersons(Set<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }


}
```

And my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hwdb2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert">org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update">org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete">org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update">org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove">org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</property>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate">org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</property>


        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping class="Main.Person" />
        <mapping class="Main.Address" />
        <mapping class="Main.ExampleListener" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I hope you have a solution for me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally updated to Hibernate 4.1.8 and the problem is solved. I had the wrong envers version which seemed to be not compatible with the hibernate version I used.